# The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, sentinel

I am using Sentinel package for advanced authentication in laravel. I can register properly, but when I am going to login then here is an error like - 'The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given.' Please anyone help me.

Here is my routes bellow:

```
 Route::get('/login', 'LoginController@login');
 Route::post('/login', 'LoginController@postLogin');
```

Here is my controller bellow:

```
 public function login(){
    return view('authentication.login');
}

public function postLogin(Request $request){
    Sentinel::authenticate($request->all());
    return Sentinel::check();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an interesting thing about laravel response. What ever you return from laravel controller as response it tries to convert that array/object into string. But to convert an object into string is possible through the PHP magic method called `__toString()`.

As you are not returning an object that has the implementation of `__toString()` method you are getting this error.

If you really want to see the output of `Sentinel::check()` then you can use `dd(Sentinel::check())` instead of returning it. Besides you can even return it like `['sentinelCheck' => Sentinel::check()]` if you really want.

Answer (score 0):

`Sentinel::check()` return a boolean, when the user is authenticated it returns the user otherwise false.

https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentinel/2.0#sentinel-check

you can use a if statement to return a response:

```
if(Sentinel::check()){
    // authenticated
} else {
    // not authenticated
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me. Fixed issue when sending array as return.

controller

```
return ['status' => true, 'msg' => 'mesaj', 'data' => 'datalar'];
```